# JPA, EclipseLink @Version +Timestamp + precision?

Tags: java, jpa, version, eclipselink

Is it possible combine persistence `@Version` + `Timestamp` + `precision`?

Expected result datetime with milliseconds 2`019-07-16 14:05:40.648419`.

Now I get `2019-07-16 14:05:18.000000`.

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Getter
@Setter
public abstract class AbstractEntity<T> {

    @Version
    @Column(name = "UPDATED", nullable = false)
    private Timestamp updated;

}
```

@Version Timestamp is set by this functionality:

```
getTimestampFromServer use -> MySQLPlatform.getTimestampQuery() //default behaviour SELECT NOW();
```

Property use-local time in persistence.xml not help, milliseconds still .000

Comment: What is the field type in the database, and what precision is "SELECT NOW()" returning?  Also, what "use-local time" property are you referring to?

Comment: The local time setting requires a customizer to set, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47997401/change-the-optimisticlockpolicy-to-use-local-time   MySQL millisecond precision support requires driver versions > 5.6.4; check the MySQLPlatform initializeConnectionData class to see what version it thinks your driver is and if the type it generates is able to store it, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9681783/496099 for details

Comment: use-local is persistence.xml <property name="eclipselink.locking.timestamp.local.default" value="true"/>.  Driver mysql-connector-java-5.1.32-bin.jar not supports milliseconds.